# Specify starting values for ViewPropertyAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation

Using `ObjectAnimator`s, optionally with `PropertyValuesHolder`s, it is possible to specify starting and ending values for the animated property:

```
ObjectAnimator animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "x", 20f, 50f);
ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "y", 30f, 100f);
AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
animSetXY.playTogether(animX, animY);
animSetXY.start();

PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", 20f, 50f);
PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", 30f, 100f);
ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(myView, pvhX, pvyY).start();
```

How can I achieve the same animation with `ViewPropertyAnimator`s? The syntax doesn't seem to support starting values, assuming they are equals to the values the view has at animation start:

```
myView.animate().x(50f).y(100f); //Where do I put starting values??
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to use ViewPropertyAnimator, your Views need to be at the start positions before the animation starts.

Comment: Worse than that, the views need to be at their start positions (values) before you even call the first ViewPropertyAnimator method.

Comment: More concretely, "myView.animate().x(50f)" prepares the animator to animate from getX() (obtained immediately) to 50f, before you call start.

Comment: any examples how?